# Add comma after every word (except final word)

Tags: php, string, replace, delimited

I've got a string (not an array, it's a load of words stored in one string) and I'd like to put a comma after every word, although not putting one after the last word. I've got;

```
echo str_replace(' ', ', ', $stilltodo);
```

but that for some reason adds a space before the comma (and after too but that's right), and also one at the end too. How could I change it to work how I want.

*An Example of the 'base' String*

```
French History Maths Physics Spanish Chemistry Biology English DT Maths History DT Spanish English French RS
```

*An Example of the Current Output with the Code above*

```
French , History , Maths , Physics , Spanish , Chemistry , Biology , English , DT , Maths , History , DT , Spanish , English , French , RS ,
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce your bug with the sample input: https://3v4l.org/WfGdc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$newstring = implode(", ", preg_split("/[\s]+/", $oldstring));
```

The [`preg_split()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) will split up your string into an array and the [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) will collapse it all back together into a single string.  The regex used in the `preg_split()` will take care of any instances you might have multiple spaces between words.

Comment: Thanks. I put `echo substr_replace($stilltodoplain ,"",-2);` on the end to anybody else having the same problem to get rid of the last comma, but I'm guessing you're right about the problem with extra spaces as this is the only one that works. Thanks again.

Comment: A regular expression is overkill here. You should really either use the `implode(explode())` method, or `rtrim()` as illustrated in my answer. Regex isn't necessarily bad, but it adds unnecessary overhead and shrouds the code's meaning somewhat.

Comment: @JamWaffles: You could consider it overkill if it's part of a function that could run tens of thousands of times an hour, but for what appears to be a one-off problem I don't think it really matters.

Comment: @Crontab Yes, of course. Regex works in this case, and isn't all that slow, but there are better ways of doing what the OP wants using more self-descriptive PHP functions.

Answer (score 4):

```
implode(', ', explode(' ', $base_string));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use implode/explode.

```
$t = "French History Maths Physics Spanish Chemistry";

// turn this into an array
$a = explode(" ", $t );

// output without final comma
echo implode(", ", $a );
```

Should get you what you want: "French, History, Maths, Physics, Spanish, Chemistry"

Answer (score 2):

Give [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) a go:

```
echo rtrim(str_replace(' ', ', ', $stilltodo, ',');
```

This will strip any comma from the end of your string. I've wrapped `str_replace()` in the `rtrim()` function to keep it on one line, but it might be clearer to split it into two.

Comment: Only variables can be passed by reference, so replace the last comma with any variable and store the comma on it

Answer (score 0):

Add comma in string without any function....its simple nd 100% working

```
<?php

$arr = array(1,2,3,4,6,8,8,8,9);

$str = '';

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {

        $str = ($str == '' ? '' : $str . ',') . $value;

}

echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

**In PHP**

Let a array as,

```
$lists=Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => 9 [2] => 10 [3] => 8 )
```

and we want it to print as `12,9,10,8`

Simply using `implode`,

Syntax:

```
implode(glue, pieces) 
$items=implode( $lists, ",");
```